# Programmatically control other nodes on Linux subnet

Tags: linux, rpc, administration

I would like to make a grid like network with few servers running Linux. Where I have a central node which should be able to schedule/execute commands on other nodes.

The central node has credentials with administrative privileges in the subnet, but I'm new to Linux, so I don't know what ?RPC? mechanisms I could use to perform the remote tasks.

Is there a tunnel, or network based command piping I could use? What keywords I should look for in Google?

If I could launch shell scripts on the remote node from the central node, I could do everything I need.

Comment: Yes, it seems it's what I needed. Copy/paste to answer for accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell )

Answer (score 2):

While SSH is enough for most tasks, in case you need something more controlled, you could use job distributing systems like [gearman](http://danga.com/gearman/), [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) or some other queues.